# Generic class of a certain base class and also inherit base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, constraints, base-class

I'm trying to create a simple DataContainer class,

```
public interface DataObject
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    uint ID { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class DataContainer<T> where T : DataObject
{
}
```

...but if I want DataContainer to also inherit DataObject - how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
[Serializable()]
public class DataContainer<T> : DataObject where T : DataObject
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { //implementation here }
        set { //implementation here }
    }

    public uint ID
    {
        get { //implementation here }
        set { //implementation here }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I only tried adding DataObject after and tried with "," between them.